# Proof: infinite parametrisation's of any non-empty subset $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Proof: there exists infinite parametrisation's of any non-empty subset $\mathbb{R}^n$

Would this suggestion for a proof be acceptable, if not why and how would I go about proving it.

let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $N\in \mathbb{N}$

let $F(x,N)=\sum _{i=i}^N \alpha _i x $

Since there are infinitely many possibilities for N there would be infinitely many possible parameterisation's. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your definition of parametrisation?

Comment: From the textbook the only definition I could find was: the definitions $x_1=F_1(P),\text{...},x_n=F_n(P)$ are said to give a parametrisation of the image of F, where P is a vector( I have used x as the vector)

Comment: What is $P$? Are the $F_i$ functions? Continuous functions? Differentiable functions? There's no way to tell if you have proved something, if you can't tell us _what are you trying to prove_.

Comment: Does the update to the question clarify?

Comment: Yes, thanks! If you want, you can type it out in MathJax, but it's fine now. I hope my comment didn't sound to harsh (sometimes text does not convey intentions so clearly), I honestly didn't understand what you were asking.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the comments, that allows me to fix the question such that it becomes understandable and hopefully useful for other people. Much better than a straight down vote as you get from some people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construction does not prove that *any* set has a parametrization. You don't even start with a fixed set and try to parametrize it.

Your definitions assume no regularity on the functions, so if $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ is any non empty *infinite* set, the inclusion
$$
\begin{align*}
 & f :  Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m \\
 & \qquad \qquad y \mapsto y
\end{align*}
$$

is a possible parametrization (i.e it sends each point $(y_1, \dots, y_m) \in Y$ to itself) and composing with any bijection $Y \to Y$ gives another parametrization. There are infinitely many such bijections, so there will be infinitely many parametrizations.

If on the contrary $Y = \{y_1, \dots, y_n\}$ is finite,

$$
\begin{align*}
& f_n : \mathbb{R}^m \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m \\
& \qquad p \mapsto \cases{y_i \text{ if $p = (n+i,n+i)$} \\ y_1 \text{ otherwise}}
\end{align*}
$$

is a family of parametrizations.

It is worth noting that the notion of parametrization here is very weak. Usually more regularity is required, such as $f$ being continuous/differentable and/or the domain being open. For example, a standard definition of a parametrizated curve $\mathcal{C}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous function $\alpha : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\operatorname{im} \alpha  = \mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on: and composing with any bijection.

Comment: Yes, of course. A bijection of $Y$ is a function $g : Y \to Y$ that is injective and surjective, i.e. the assignment is a one to one correspondence. In particular the image of any bijection on $Y$ is still $Y$, so by composing $fg$ is still a parametrization: $im(fg) = fg(Y) = f(Y) = Y$.

Comment: cont.  This will give new parametrizations,  but how many? Well, at least countably many, since there are infinitely many bijections. Since $Y$ is infinite, it contains some countably infinite subset $y_1, y_2, \dots$. Now, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the following is a bijection

$$
g_n (y) = \cases{y_n \text{ if $y = y_1$}\\ y_1 \text{ if $y = y_n$} \\ y \text{ otherwise} }
$$

which swaps $y_1$ with $y_n$ and leaves everything else in place.